# Simulate application installation from app store to collect ad campaign data

Tags: ios, debugging, ads, appsflyer

I need to extract advertisement campaign data on the first application launch using AppsFlyer, specifically source(pid) and campaign(c). I'm doing it using AppsFlyer SDK methods according to the [guide](https://dev.appsflyer.com/docs/direct-deep-linking). To debug the solution I'm making TestFlight package and referencing it with link like:

`https://testflight.apple.com/join/some-id?pid=test&c=testCompaign`

But neither `pid` nor `c` is passed to the app when I install the app using this link.

How can I debug `pid`/`c` to be sure it will be passed to the app at the production?